# TileItem Click Event not working properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, devexpress, mouseevent

I have a TileItem in a tilecontrol (DevExpress). On click this method is fired

```
private void tileItem1_ItemClick_1(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (GetForegroundWindow() == Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It is focused!");
                //do some magic here
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It is not focused!");
                this.Activate();
            }
        }
```

My problem is that even if my form is not focused, it will think that it is focused and always triger the first condition of the if statement.
I want to activate the window when the tileitem is clicked IF the window is not focused. Isn't this the proper way to do it?
What i am thinking is that the method is triggered after the mouse is released so the window has already taken focus by that time. If this is the problem then which is the solution to achieve what i am trying to do?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Form5 : Form {

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        if (wasMouseActivated) {
            wasMouseActivated = false;
            // window was activated by a mouse click
        }
        else {
            // window already had focus
        }
    }

    private const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x21;
    private bool wasMouseActivated = false;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE) {
            wasMouseActivated = true;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: I belive there are two events triggered when clicking the form. The first is on mousedown which activated the window and then there is the mouseup which since the form has already been activated it returns that the form is active

Comment: Even though the click is used to activate the window, the OS activates the window first and then sends the mouse click to the window. The click itself only indirectly activates the window. The window is activated when it receives the corresponding `WindowMessage`.